# Maxima - a speech competition?

Tags: classical-latin

At some point in childhood I learnt there were speech competitions in ancient Rome when people would express complex ideas in very few words. And I believed since those short sentences called "maxima"

This happened couple decades before public Internet and wikipedia.

I always believed it to be common knowledge. However tried recently to find confirmation and couldn't get past "plural for maximus" copy/paste on 50 websites.

Are there real scholars of Latin and/or ancient Rome history who can **confirm or correct my understanding that maxima is a short phrase which explains a complex construct**

I don't know if this example would qualify as maxima in ancient times but looks good to me:

*If you tell the truth you don’t have to remember anything. – Mark Twain*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word *maxima [sententia]* indicates a sentence that is a general truth or is generally assumed to be true.

Not necessarily it explains a complex context, you can instead think of a *maxima* as an axiom, that for its evidence becomes a foundation or a rule of behaviour. It is a "*maxima*" sentence because of its universal validity.

*Maxima* is still present in English as "maxim",
 in Italian as "massima", which have the same meaning.

Comment: Actually. Your version of what maxima is could be one of the definitions. I am pretty sure there were competitions in ancient Rome who says best maxima. In that context my definition fits (people would hardly compete in stating obvious)